# How do i get PostgreSQL on Open BSD 7.0 to run

Tags: postgresql, openbsd

Trying to start postgresql on openbsd 7.0 but can't seem to get it to work. so far I tried [this tutorial](https://fluca1978.github.io/2021/10/09/PostgreSQLOnOpenBSD.html)
and looking around a bit on google. I'm new to OpenBSD.

```
# rcctl -df start postgresql 
doing _rc_parse_conf
doing _rc_quirks
postgresql_flags empty, using default >-D /var/postgresql/data -w -l /var/postgresql/logfile<
doing rc_check
pg_ctl: no server running
postgresql
doing rc_start
doing _rc_wait start
doing rc_check
pg_ctl: no server running
waiting for server to start.... stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
doing _rc_rm_runfile
(failed)
# ls -al /var/run
total 176
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel      512 Jan 17 01:30 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root  wheel      512 Jan 16 17:30 ..
srw-rw----   1 root  crontab      0 Jan 16 16:57 cron.sock
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    49152 Jan 16 16:57 dev.db
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     5945 Jan 16 16:57 dmesg.boot
-r--r--r--   1 root  wheel    14592 Jan 16 17:30 ld.so.hints
srw-rw----   1 root  wheel        0 Jan 16 16:57 ntpd.sock
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel      512 Jan 16 18:48 rc.d
srw-rw-rw-   1 root  wheel        0 Jan 16 16:57 smtpd.sock
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel        6 Jan 16 16:57 sshd.pid
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel        6 Jan 16 16:57 syslog.pid
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  utmp      7296 Jan 18 19:26 utmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to complete the following steps in the tutorial to successfully start `postgresql`:

```
# mkdir /var/postgresql/data
# chown _postgresql:_postgresql /var/postgresql/data
# su -l _postgresql
$ initdb -D /var/postgresql/data
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "_postgresql".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "C".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "SQL_ASCII".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 20
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... UTC
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/postgresql/data -l logfile start
```

You *can* start using the command printed by `initdb`, but better is to `exit` the user session and use what the tutorial recommends:

```
# rcctl start postgresql
```

Be sure to carefully follow the rest of the tutorial, or `postgresql` won't start after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

After you run `pkg_add postgresql-server` the system will point you to a package readme that you should read:

```
New and changed readme(s):
        /usr/local/share/doc/pkg-readmes/postgresql-server
```

This readme has the remainder of the instructions for getting postgresql up and running on an OpenBSD machine.